# How to draw straight line to the mouse coordinates?

Tags: c#, winforms

When user press the left button and move the mouse it should appears a straight line(not permanent line) from previous point to the current mouse moving position. Finally a real straight line will appear when the user releases the left mouse. please help me ..how do i do it?

```
      List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

     private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
           points.Add(e.Location);
           pictureBox1.Invalidate();
       }
     }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         if (points.Count > 1)
         e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points.ToArray());
     }
```

Comment: Copy the MouseDown code without the Add to the MouseMove event.

Comment: please read the question and its explanation properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for

```
private Stack<Point> points = new Stack<Point>();
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    points.Clear();
    points.Push(e.Location);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Count > 1)
    {
        points.Pop();
    }
    if (points.Count > 0 && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        points.Push(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (points.Count > 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, points.ToArray());
}
```

I used `Stack` for ease of use, you are free to change to whatever collection of your choice.

To draw several line you can do something like this

```
private Stack<Line> lines = new Stack<Line>();
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lines.Push(new Line { Start = e.Location });
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (lines.Count > 0 && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lines.Peek().End = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, line.Start, line.End);
    }
}

class Line
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your code is working fine but whenever i click on picture box for new line ,the previous line will disappear how can i resolve it...

Comment: So you need to draw N number of lines?

Comment: i need to draw shapes like square,triangle etc ..from point to point.....according to user requirement.

Comment: @GopalNavi Updated my answer, If you need more info about how to draw other shapes you can ask new question since that's a different question :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use mentioned code

```
 Point currentPoint = new Point();
  private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Line line = new Line();

            line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

            paintSurface.Children.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess question is in Winforms